# How to make iframe using HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have html file, but I don't know how to make  code to embed in website.

1. open html file in chrome site → open developer tools ([F12] key button) → copy all source code

I think this method is something wrong.... Is that right?

2. open html file in chrome site → got url (ex. https:/C:/~~/~.html) → create iframe code like this.

[iframe src="url"][/iframe]

I tested that code, but not working.

Do you have any other method or program you know?

Comment: Where is that file hosted, you can't access C drive with https protocol. Are you saying you want to add an arbitrary iframe and load its content from your local system into a third-party website? For that you have to build a plug-in.

Comment: Yes. How can I build a plug-in?

Comment: You can't. I'm sorry, I've used a bit bad terminology in the comment above, plug-ins are obsoleted, I meant [Browser extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions).

Comment: When html file is uploaded in google drive, Is it also impossible?

Comment: You can test it yourself. With the DevTools, write to the console: `x=document.createElement('iframe')` ENTER, `x.src='URLtoThe Resource'` ENTER, `document.body.appendChild(x)` ENTER. But notice, that the code in the iframe can't interact with the main page. Doing the above on this page using "https://example.com" as an URL, an iframe appears below the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com" height="200" width="400">
```

And the [] and [/] is for BBCode for forms normal html is <> and </>